# php script isn't working on server while works on localhost [xampp]

Tags: php, mysqli

while running on xampp this code works but on web server only blank page appears.
Please help !

> PHP version: Xampp: 7.2.7 Server:7.1.18

```
<?php
 require_once("config.php");
 $bar=$conn->query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m')as mn,sum(amount)as am FROM 
 ENTRY WHERE sale_status='paid' OR sale_status='in process' AND YEAR(date) = 
 YEAR(CURDATE()) GROUP BY mn");
    while($arr=$bar->fetch_assoc()){
        $arry[array_shift($arr)]=$arr['am'];
    }

$bar2=$conn->query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m')as mn,sum(amount)as am FROM ENTRY WHERE sale_status='chargeback' OR sale_status='refund' OR sale_status='fraud' OR sale_status='adjusted' AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) GROUP BY mn");
    while($arr2=$bar2->fetch_assoc()){
        $arry2[array_shift($arr2)]=$arr2['am'];
    }
$arr3=array();
for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
    if(!array_key_exists(sprintf("%02d",$i), $arry)){
        $arry[sprintf("%02d",$i)]="0";
    }
    if(!array_key_exists(sprintf("%02d",$i), $arry2)){
        $arry2[sprintf("%02d",$i)]="0";
    }
    echo $arry[sprintf("%02d",$i)]-$arry2[sprintf("%02d",$i)].",";
}
?>
```

Comment: Rename your function to something else as you may be calling js native function with that name.

Comment: tried that, didn't work @KarloKokkak

Comment: try my answer, don't use form submit. someone has derated it, I don't what is wrong with that. If there is a problem with that please comment. But it is 100% correct.

Answer (score 0):

Prevent submission by doing a return false inside form's `onsubmit` attribute. Also renamed custom function `alert()` to something else so it doesn't mess with js native function with the same name.

**Try:**

```
<form method="post" id="eform" onsubmit="return alert2();">
Name<input type="text" name="name" required>
URL<input type="text" name="link" required>
<button type="submit" value="submit">Submit Me</button>
</form>
```

**And**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function alert2(){
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "enq.php",
    data:$('#eform').serialize() + "&uname=<?=@$u_name?>&pname=<?=@$titlename?>",
    success: function(msg) {
        if(msg!=""){
            alert("Query Successfully sent ! Msg: " + msg);
        }
        else{
            alert("Some Error");
        }
    }
}); 
    return false;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation() to prevent page reload on submit. event.stopPropagation() will work on firefox browser.

Do change the form attributes as below:

```
<form method="post" id="eform" name="eform" onsubmit="alert()">
Name<input type="text" name="name" required>
URL<input type="text" name="link" required>
<button type="submit" value="submit"></button>
</form>
```

And write the javascript as below:-

```
$('form[name=eform]').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  $.ajax({
     url: '../enq.php',
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: $(this).serialize(),
     success: function(result){
        // your success script
     },
     error: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
       // your error scripts
     }
  });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use button type as submit, use type button or use anchor tag and put some css to view it as a button.When you use button type as submit It's using normal form submit without js.

```
<button type="button" onClick="save()" value="submit"></button>
```

And also don't use alert function, It's already define function in Js. use something like save.